# implementing Facebook login onto Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I'm really new to programming started the end of December.

I'm have a problem trying to implementing Facebook login onto Xcode. I've tried using the Facebook method but i came across a problem because was written 'object C', i came across a youtube turoiral but turns out its old, i came across another tutorial that lend me down a path using 'Cocoapods'.ive looked through a number of questions on here and took what i understand and still to no avail, so far the only thing I've managed to correct every time is download the relevant SDKs and put the right info onto the info.plist.

can someone please point me in the right direction as to how write the code from the App delegates point because thats where i seem to just crash n burn.

your help would be much appreciated.
free strength and conditioning advice is the only thing i have to offer in return at this moment in time because I'm new to using programming.

Comment: If you really want to implement Facebook SDK in iOS app. Please walk by via this link and dont skip any word from doc. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

Comment: Hi Nitin I've tried this way but once i get step 5 i just get errors

Comment: Then you should post what error you get and what the way you are trying on instead of write just description. and you probably missed some steps to add app id.